# how to make a web portal kind website in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi to every one I am new to the asp.net so I need to know how can i make a web portal in asp.net with five roles. actually its like this there are four type of roles like agent log in, customer log in, Hospitals log in, Health Adviser log in. the process is if customer buy a product from company then he need to go under health checkup. the health checkup report will be given by hospital to agent and agent will be uploading this report according to the customer id when customer is log in the he will get is reports please get me any detail how i can start and do the things. thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Your first step is to follow some tutorials, say from here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials. When you actually have some code we may be able to help

Comment: thanks for replying I wiil be going through the tutorial then get back to you